# Would compiler optimize conditional statement in loop by moving it ouside the loop?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

Here is the C code:

```
struct node{
    void *value;
    struct node *next;
};

void g(void *p){
    /*...*/
}

void f(struct node *head, const int ok){
    struct node *p=head;

    while (p){
        /* ...
           code 1 
           ...
         */
        if (ok!=0){
            g(p->value);
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

I used gcc to compile this code. If I compiled with `-O`, would it optimize function `f` like this:

```
void f(struct node *head, const int ok){
    struct node *p=head;

    if (ok!=0){
        while (p){
            /* ...
               code 1 
               ...
             */
            g(p->value);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
    else{
        while (p){
            /* ...
               code 1 
               ...
             */
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could hoist it out of the loop. Why not check?

Comment: You can instruct most compilers to show you the assembly code. So you can check that yourself fairly easily.

Comment: "Would compiler optimize XYZ" - well, what did you deduce from the generated asembly (which you **have** checked before asking, right?)

Comment: Also, this smells very well like premature optimization.

Comment: OT: Why not put `/* code 1 */` into a macro or better inline function, use the second approach and go on?

Comment: @alk, or if it's large, even a not-inline function.

Comment: @Shahbaz: .. or use `-O3 -funswitch-loops`, as you were so kind to look up it's docs .. :-)

Comment: @alk, haha, yes. Although even though the man page says that, I'm not sure if it would do it in **all** cases. There's probably a heuristic that decides if it's worth the waste of space or not.

Comment: Note that the file produced with `-fdump-tree-optimized` can be much easier to read than the asm and has most of the high-level optimizations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would greatly depend on how big `/* code 1 */` is. If it is very small, it might. But if it is anything above a few lines, it most probably won't. Duplicating a large amount of code for every single `if` would have terrible effects on the performance. In fact, that may happen with very aggressive optimization and certainly not just with `-O`. From the man page of `gcc` (emphasis mine):

> -O
>   -O1 ...
>
> With -O, the compiler tries to **reduce code size *and* execution time**, without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time.

So reducing code is also part of optimization.

> -O2 Optimize even more.  GCC performs nearly all supported optimizations that **do not involve a space-speed tradeoff**.  As compared to -O, this option increases
>   both compilation time and the performance of the generated code.

So `-O2` wouldn't do what you want either.

> -O3 Optimize yet more.  -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2 and also turns on the `-finline-functions`, `-funswitch-loops`, `-fpredictive-commoning`,
>    `-fgcse-after-reload`, `-ftree-vectorize` and `-fipa-cp-clone` options.

Now we have to look at these options to see if any of them might do what you want:

> `-funswitch-loops`
>    Move branches with loop invariant conditions out of the loop, with duplicates of the loop on both branches (modified according to result of the condition).

Voila! With `-O3` you get the optimization you want.

Comment: +1 for through explanation and referencing the man pages.
But I would like to add that if all OP really wants is to unswitch-loops, they can just use -funswitch-loops without -O3.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on many things.

Since, you are using `gcc`, you can always check if it did for a particular program by invoking `gcc -o -S fileName.c`

Answer (score 2):

In these kind of situations I find this website http://gcc.godbolt.org/ quite useful