# Compilers, If statements and loops

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction

This is a general efficiency question for c++. I am not familiar with the inner workings of compilers, so suppose I have several loops and a potential if statement inside, e.g.:

```
for(int i=0; ...) 
{
    for(int j=0; ...)
    { 
        if( ... )
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ... (slightly different)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this if-statement is independent of the loops. Is there a significant speed difference if I instead define the if/else statement outside of the loops with the loops inside? E.g.:

```
if( ... )
{
    for(int i=0; ...) 
    {
        for(int j=0; ...)
        { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for(int i=0; ...) 
    {
        for(int j=0; ...)
        { 
            ... (slightly different)
        }
    }
}
```

If so, or if not so, why is that? I have some notion that a compiler will recognize the same if statement being done over and over, but this is quite unfamiliar territory to me.

I examined the response to this question:
[Would compiler optimize conditional statement in loop by moving it ouside the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083769/would-compiler-optimize-conditional-statement-in-loop-by-moving-it-ouside-the-lo)
and he discusses the different levels of optimization in gcc, and how -O3 (I think) would do that. But is anything done like this automatically? If not, how big of a cost is an if-statement like this inside of a loop?

Comment: Even if your compiler doesn't optimize your code into the second form, your processor's branch prediction should handle this easily with minimal overhead.

Comment: you can move the code into two functions and pick one before the loop.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but same idea. It's a video where Mr. Lavavej trying to convince us not to disturb the compiler doing it's job. Link: [Don’t Help the Compiler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler).

Comment: @Drop, I agree that one should not prematurely optimize and try to second guess the compiler when performance is not the main consideration.  However, when it's time for optimization and you need yet more performance then you should defiantly NOT trust the compiler.  You should consider all options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real answer is maybe.  If the condition is a loop
invariant, then the transposition you suggest is legal, and if
the compiler can recognize the loop invariance, then it can make
the transposition.  Whether it does or not depends on the
compiler: `g++ /O3` does, at least in 64 bit mode, `cl /Ox /Os`
doesn't, at least in 32 bit mode; g++ also unrolls the two loops.
In my tests, at least; I more or less guaranteed that the
compiler could determine that the condition was a loop invariant
by wrapping the loop in a function, with the condition
a function argument of type `bool const`; depending on the
condition, it may be more or less difficult for the compiler to
prove loop invariance.  And of course, the fact that the
compiler has more registers to play with in 64 bit mode could
also affect its optimizations .

Also: although I'd instinctively expect the g++ version to be
faster, it is significantly larger; in some cases, this may
negatively affect the various memory caches, resulting in the
code actually running slower.

In the end, I'd write the first, always.  If the profiler later
shows it to be a bottleneck, there's no issue about going back
and rewriting it along the lines of the second, then measuring
to see if it makes a difference, one way or the other, and how
much difference it makes.  And be aware that the best results
may depend on the compiler and the architecture you are
targetting.

Answer (score 2):

This question is impossible to say which is quicker.

Just remember the 80-20 rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle#In_software) and find the bit of code by profiling.

Anyway just write the code readable and maintainable in the first place. If you have performance problems profile the code.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on case but I would bet second option is faster. This is because no branching will happen and compiler has higher chance to replace lot of code with some MMX/SSE group of instructions.

Also at least theoretically in first case CPU has to solve same if() in each for() cycle. In second case if() is outside of look and should be faster. But again, modern compilers often can find this problem and solve it magically.

But yes, usually it is important to write code for readability unless performance is real big concern.

Comment: It depends on the compiler.  A good compiler will optimize the first case into the second if it makes sense _and_ if it can prove that the condition is a loop invariant.

Comment: All people say "depends on compiler" but it also depends on code. Some code is not so easy to understand even for compiler. Depends on both. I agree, good compiler can do good job. But not miracles.

Comment: The real key to what the compiler can do is my second clause: "_if_ it can prove that the condition is a loop invariant."  If the programmer knows that it is a loop invariant, but thinks the compiler may not be able to see it, using it to initialize a `bool const` variable outside the loops might be all that is needed for the compiler to do the optimization.